# Asking moderators favors when looking at questions

Tags: discussion, comments, close-reasons

Some of my questions were on-hold and closed. As everyone knows, it comes a yellow rectangle where it explains what it means and why is your question not so good.
For example:

[image: Yellow rectangle]

Sometimes, this rectangle doesn't explain enough why was the question closed or put on-hold.

Is it okay to write in the question:

> I'm a bit new in this site and I would like to know what were my mistakes if this question is going to be closed or on-hold. Please write at the comments what were the problems.

Or is it redundant? Will people take this as bad? I'm asking this because many times they can put the question closed or on-hold, and the explanation in the rectangle isn't enough for understanding the mistakes.

Will these moderators explain the problem at the comments as I asked?

Comment: Note that on Stack Exchange, "moderators" is commonly taken to mean people with a diamond attached to their name (see for example Qmechanic here who edited the tags of this question). In the case you use as an example, no (current) "diamond moderator" was involved in the closure. A moderator may still step in and offer an explanation from their point of view, but it will be based on their understanding of the question and the reasons why those other people voted to close. See e.g. [Who are the site moderators, and what is their role here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Asking for close-reasons in comments is of course totally fine. And moderators and other Phys.SE users try to leave comments whenever the standard close-reason banner is insufficient.

But do keep in mind that moderators and other Phys.SE users are not paid, and it might be difficult to serve everyone in a timely fashion.

Also note that scope and close-reasons are further explained on [help pages](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help) and various [Phys.SE meta posts](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Alternatively, you can try to ask for clarification in the [h-bar chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar) (requires 20+ reputation points).

If the above didn't work, you can also post a new meta question.

Comment: What do you mean by *hbar*?

Comment: @PichiWuana : Added link.

Comment: @PichiWuana And it may get more notice if you ask here on meta for clarification of why a particular post was closed (be sure to include a link to the original question). Otherwise people may not notice that you asked a question in the comments of the original question.

Comment: Well explained, I agree with this. Two things I'd emphasize: (1) Although asking for clarification is fine, the place to do it is _not_ in the question itself. (2) Make sure you do read the reason in the yellow box, including the link, if there is one. If your request for clarification makes it seem like you didn't read the feedback already given to you, it's not going to be well received. (cc @Pichi)

Comment: @DavidZ A question about **(1)**, where would be the place you recommend to ask for clarifications?

Comment: For 1) Either comments or meta post. and not question itself.

Comment: @PichiWuana I'd try first the comments on the post, then the chat room, then making a new meta post if neither of those worked.

Comment: We don't have a homework close reason on [SQA](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/). Does the homework close reason generate a flag if it's closed without comment?